With little networks with few parameters pytorch seems to be very slow in training speed respect to tensorflow. Am i missing something?
I am currently working with small structured networks and even if Pytorch seems to be the obvious choice due to its high flexibility, it still drops a lot in terms of training speed compared to TensorFlow.
As I could see after 10 training sessions, PyTorch seems to double in training time. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to improve the computational time of Pytorch?
I've made a Google Colab to reproduce the same network in both PyTorch/TensorFlow to compare the two models.
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import time
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,TensorDataset
import numpy as np

## Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0005
num_of_epochs = 300
batch_size = 128

## Create Data
xx=torch.arange(40*640*60, dtype=torch.float32).view(640*60, 40)
ff=torch.arange(1*640*60, dtype=torch.float32).view(640*60, 1)
out=torch.arange(1*640*60, dtype=torch.float32).view(640*60, 1)

## Define the model
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin = nn.Linear(40, 1, False)
        self.par = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(1))

    def forward(self, x, f):
        return torch.add(self.lin(x),self.par*f)

model = Model()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_fun = torch.nn.MSELoss()

dataset = TensorDataset(xx,ff,out)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)


%%time
## Training
model.train(True)
for i in range(n_train):
    start = time.time()
    for iter in range(num_of_epochs):
        train_loss = []
        for x, f, y in train_dataloader:
            # Zero your gradients for every batch!
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Make predictions for this batch
            out = model(x, f)

            # Compute the loss and its gradients
            loss = loss_fun(out, y)
            loss.backward()

            # Adjust learning weights
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss.append(loss.item())
        train_loss = np.mean(train_loss)
    end = time.time()
    exe_time['pytorch'].append(end-start)

Full code can be found here

You need to transfer your model and data to GPU to benefit from GPU computation. First you should check that you indeed have access to a CUDA device.
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model.train(True)
model.to(device) # Transfer model to device
for i in range(n_train):
    start = time.time()
    for iter in range(num_of_epochs):
        train_loss = []
        for x, f, y in train_dataloader:
            # Zero your gradients for every batch!
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Transfer data to device
            x, f = x.to(device), f.to(device)

            # Make predictions for this batch
            out = model(x, f)

